# Fetching relation to PFObject cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, pfobject

I have a `PFUser` that has a `days` relation to a `Day` `PFObject`.

In my database it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "WjLAnMuRmp",
    "name": "c",
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2016-08-04T15:28:51.759Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2016-08-24T19:44:44.774Z"
    },
    "days": [
        {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Day",
            "objectId": "BrQwmKAbJC"
        },
        {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "Day",
            "objectId": "6wuDMl4kKI"
        }
    ]
}
```

Pretty straight forward. In my cloud code, I'm trying to send up a `PFUser` `objectId`, then fetch all the `days` they have and iterate over them. For some strange reason I keep getting 0 returned when I do a relation query.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getDayAveragesForUser", function(request, response) {

  console.log("-getDayAveragesForUser");

  // Create the query on the User class
  var fetchedUser = new Parse.User({id:request.params.userObjectId});

  console.log("the fetched user: " + fetchedUser.id);

  var relation = fetchedUser.relation("days");

  var query = relation.query();
  query.limit(365);
  query.ascending("createdAt");
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " Days.");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

When I print the `fetchedUser.id` it's correct so I know I'm on the right user. This seems based on the documentation example:

```
var relation = user.relation("likes");
relation.query().find({
  success: function(list) {
    // list contains the posts that the current user likes.
  }
});
```

This should be working fine.

===

I just add this to my Cloud Code to test:

```
  var days = fetchedUser.get("days");

  console.log("type of: " + typeof days);
```

which from this I get:

```
type of: undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your days are not saved as relations but as a pointers. And in parse relations and pointers are handled in different ways. 
In order to fetch the days pointer you need to change your query to look like the following:

```js
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.include("days"); // include the days pointer in the results
userQuery.get(request.params.userObjectId, {
  success: function(user) {
    // This function will *not* be called.
    console.log(user.get("days")); // print the days to console
  },
  error: function(error) {


  }
});
```